# Derivation of the Gamma approximation formula from the Delta approximation formula

Tags: black-scholes, delta, gamma

The formula of $Gamma = (Vplus + Vminus - 2V0)/(V0 * dS^2)$, where

- $V$ is the contract value,
- $S$ is the stock price.

We also know that $Gamma = (Dplus-Dminus)/(Splus-Sminus)$,
where

- $D$ is the contract Delta,
- $Splus = S0 + dS$,
- $Sminus = S0 - dS$,
- $Dplus = (Vplus - V0)/(V0 * dS)$,
- $Dminus = (V0 - Vminus)/(V0 * dS)$.

Substituting $Dplus$, $Dminus$, and replacing $Splus-Sminus$ with $2dS$ we get: 
$(Vplus + Vminus - 2V0)/(V0 * dS)/2dS = (Vplus + Vminus - 2V0)/(V0 * 2 * dS^2)$

I must be doing something wrong, because **1/2** is not present in the book formula. 
 Could you, please, help me with the derivation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Welcome to Quant SE. It looks like you haven't made up your mind on whether your shock is $dS$ or $S_0dS$. Also, $V_0$ doesn't belong in the denominator. You probably mean $S_0$. Please try to use Latex on this site next time you visit.)

It's better to start with [Taylor's theorem with remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) to convince yourself of the validity of these finite difference schemes:

$$V(S+dS)= V(S)+V'(S)dS+\boxed{\frac{1}{2}V''(S)(dS)^2}+ \frac{1}{6}V'''(S_1)(dS)^3$$

for some $S_1\in (S, S+dS)$
$$V(S-dS)= V(S)-V'(S)dS+\boxed{\frac{1}{2}V''(S)(dS)^2}-\frac{1}{6}V'''(S_2)(dS)^3$$
for some $S_2\in (S-dS, S)$

We then get (note that the two halves in the boxes will make sure there is no $2$ in the final denominator):

$$ \frac{V(S+dS)+V(S-dS)-2V(S)}{(dS)^2} = V''(S)+ \frac{1}{6}(V'''(S_1) + V'''(S_2))dS$$

and finally we let $dS \rightarrow 0$.

Replacing $dS$ by $SdS$ everywhere, we also get:

$$ \frac{V(S+SdS)+V(S-SdS)-2V(S)}{S^2(dS)^2} \approx V''(S),$$

for small $dS$.

Comment: Many thanks for the derivation! The original equations come from FRM Part I 2012 preparation by Kaplan and reference GARP Reading - Tuckman, Chapter 5.

Comment: @Ragewave No problem. Consider accepting one of the answers.

Comment: Ok, done! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Also, I do not think Gamma = (Dplus-Dminus)/(Splus-Sminus) is correct, rather it is Gamma = (Dplus-Dminus)/(dS). You must use the increment dS throughout, for consistency. By making the denominator be a 2*dS step you are not correctly differentiating with respect to the variable "S".